Is it possible to host an HTML/CSS/JS website on GitHub Pages without exposing the source code?
Could someone please provide guidance on how to host an HTML/CSS/JS website on GitHub Pages while keeping the source code private? Alternatively, are there any other free platforms or methods that would allow me to accomplish this without exposing the source code?
I have looked into making the repository private, but I'm not sure i think the live version of the website will be not accessible if the repository is set to private.Please tell me, If there are any alternative methods or free platforms that would allow me to achieve this goal.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Does this answer your question? How to hide static files on React app deployed to Github pages?
